# UI Testing with Hilt

Tags: kotlin, ui-testing, dagger-hilt, mockk

I am trying to mock a view model in my UI Tests. It seems like I don't have it set up correctly, because the VM in the test activity is "not initialized".

This is what I got:

1. Hilt Module that provides my VM:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideMainViewModel(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): MainViewModel = MainViewModel(sharedPreferences)
}
```

2. Test Module to provide mocks:

```kotlin
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [ApplicationModule::class]
)
object MockModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideMainViewModel(): MainViewModel = mockk(relaxed = true)
}
```

3. In my UI test:

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidTest
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val showError = MutableLiveData<String>()

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        Intents.init()
        every { viewModel.showError } returns showError
    }

    @After
    fun cleanUp() {
        Intents.release()
        unmockkAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun testThis() {
        val activityScenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity> = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    }
```

However, when I run the test, the view model is not a mock!
What am I missing?

Comment: I dont know Hilt, but I guess it does not work, because you init your Mock outside of your Test. Also when you want to Mock a MainViewModel relaxed you should do it like this: val mock = mockk<MainViewModel>(relaxed = true)

Answer (score 0):

Hilt only injects its objects (inside a test) after you call `hiltRule.inject()`, but you're trying to access `viewModel` before that, and that's why `viewModel` isn't initialized. Try putting `hiltRule.inject()` as the first line inside `init`:

```
@Before
fun init() {
    hiltRule.inject()
    every { viewModel.showError } returns showError
    Intents.init()
}
```